# why there is different `User-Agent` for same browser

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, http, http-headers, user-agent

I have a created a local node server and when i'm printing `User-Agent` from `req` of GET request, like:

```
router.get('**', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.header('User-Agent')) {
        console.log('user-agent = ', (req.header('User-Agent')))
        res.end(req.header('User-Agent'));
    } else {
        res.send('Hello World!!!')
    }
});
```

then it print different `User-Agent` for `/` path and `/favicon.ico` path for my **One Plus** device.

result:-

> `/` = Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; ONEPLUS A3003 Build/OPR6.170623.013) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.109 Mobile Safari/537.36
>
> `/favicon.ico` = Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; Build/OPR6.170623.013) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.109 Mobile Safari/537.36

why these two different User-Agent is comming from same browser.

I'm testing this on Chrome browser.